# Why the constructor is being called instead of giving me an error?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I was building a system for serializing a class to a string and send it through the network for an educational game I'm doing as internship. And it works like a charm. But suddenly I noticed myself looking at my code wondering "**How the heck is this working?**".

The class I'm talking about is pasted below without all unnecessary parts.

```
[Serializable]
public class Question : ISerializable
{

    public readonly int id;
    // Some more
    // variables

    // Default Constructor
    public Question (int id /*, some more parameters*/)
    {
        this.id = id;
        // Some initialization code
    }

    // Pay attention to this Constructor
    public Question (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        id = (int)info.GetValue ("id", typeof (int));
        // Some deserialization code
    }

    // Serialization overload method
    public void GetObjectData (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue ("id", id, typeof (int));
        // Some serialization code
    }

    // Serialization method actually used
    static public string SerializeToString (Question p)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ())
        {
            bf.Serialize (ms, p);
            return Convert.ToBase64String (ms.ToArray ());
        }
    }

    // This is where I'm going crazy
    static public Question DeserializeFromString (string serialized)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream (Convert.FromBase64String (serialized)))
        {
            return (Question)bf.Deserialize (ms);
        }
    }

}
```

If I do this in the server side:

```
    // ...
    string serialized = Question.SerializeToString (actualQuestion);
    // Send "serialized" through the network
    // ...
```

And this in the client side:

```
    // ...
    // Receive a string
    Question receivedQuestion = Question.DeserializeFromString (receivedString);
    // ...
```

**It works! But why?**

What I want to know is what is exactly going under the hood in the return statement of DeserializeFromString.

```
return (Question)bf.Deserialize (ms);
```

Here is what I actually understand:
bf.Deserialize (ms) receives a memory stream populated with the string of the serialization and returns a Object of the deserialized data.

1. How the variables are stored in the Object since it doesn't know its prototype? (it doesn't know which class was serialized)
2. Why (Question)someObjectOfTypeObject is calling the special Constructor instead of searching for an overload of a explicit conversion, or, a Constructor that receives an Object (and failing in those searches as I didn't implement neither of them)?

I would like to understand what is going on at a low level (or at least at the compiler and runtime level) and, if possible, explanations about what is happening in the memory.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't know what class was serialized? Surely that's going to be item #1 in the serialized data.

Comment: The binary formatter *does* include information about the structure that it serialized.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I thought that it doesn't know because, in my mind, the returned object was an instance of Object and not a instance of Question referenced by its supertype Object. Well, my bad, it's kinda obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it doesn't know which class was serialized

It *does* know, BinaryFormatter includes the type info for the serialized object in the stream.  It records the assembly display name, the assembly version, the assembly's public key token, the namespace name and the type name.  And for each field in the class, it records the field name as well as the field type, done the same way as the object type.

Note how this tends to make binary serialization a bit dangerous, the code that deserializes the data needs to be able to find the *exact* same assembly back. Tends to be difficult after a couple of years.

Get more insight by serializing to a FileStream, use a hex viewer to look at the data.  You'll readily see the extra metadata back.

> Why (Question)someObjectOfTypeObject is calling the special Constructor

Because you inherited ISerializable.  BinaryFormatter checks if you implemented that interface and then automatically goes looking for a constructor that takes the SerializationInfo and StreamingContext arguments.

The much more interesting case is where you *don't* implement ISerializable.  BinaryFormatter then pulls a stunt that you can't pull off yourself, it creates an object *without* calling a constructor.  It uses a backdoor into the CLR to do this.  Setting the field values then reconstructs the object the way it was stored in memory when it was originally serialized.

Comment: Ok, first question is answered and I'm satisfied. But not about the second one. I can't see the difference between the following code and the one in my question, in the matter of what happens when deciding which function to call. `Object obj = new Object(); return (Question)obj;` What makes this code search for a explicit conversion overload (or perhaps a constructor that receives an object?) and the code in the question search for that special constructor?

Comment: AND, that thing you said that happens when I don't implement the interface. Backdoor into the CLR and stuff. WOW. That is hard to understand at first but I'll study more about that. And you made me go [like this](http://memestorage.com/_nw/51/76378097.jpeg) when I read it.

Comment: The crazy magic happens in `bf.Deserialize(ms)` - that returns a `Question` object, not a plain `Object`. `(Question)someObjectOfTypeObject` is just a cast, because the compiler doesn't know that the object will be a `Question`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard So, if I replace `(Question)someObjectOfType` with `someObjectOfType as Question` will work too?